# Stable analytic manifold under simple action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, ac.commutative-algebra, group-actions

For an integer $m > 1$, let us define the action
$$
f: X_i \to (1+X_i)^{m} - 1 
$$
on $C[[X_1,...,X_N]]$, where $C$ is the complex number field. Consider the analytic manifold $V(I)$ defined by the ideal $I$ in $C[[X_1,...,X_N]]$.

Question: For which $V(I)$ is it possible that $V(I)$ is stable under the action $f$? 
Equivalently for which $I$ do we have that $f(I) = I$?

Comment: I made some syntactical changes to your question and formatted formulas to make it clearer. If I misunderstood something, feel free to re-edit.

Comment: Why is $f$ an action? $f$ takes a non-unit to a unit!